# Canvas getMaximumBitmapWidth and getMaximumBitmapHeight functionality

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

How does the methods of `Canvas`, `getMaximumBitmapWidth()` and `getMaximumBitmapHeight()`, works out.

These methods are non-static and seems to be returning static final value according to [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Canvas.java)

Why make the methods non-static, if the values does not change with the instance?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because there's different types of Canvas in the internals of the system, for example a software one, and a hardware accelerated one.
On a hardware accelerated one, the texture size limit comes from the hardware, which can be obtained from GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE.

Bye,